# Datalog require field `unlock'

Tags: ocaml, datalog

While compiling an OCaml application I get the following error:

```
  File "/tmp/ocamlpp466ee0", line 308, characters 34-233:
  Error: Signature mismatch:
   ...
   The field `unlock' is required but not provided
   The field `lock' is required but not provided
  Command exited with code 2.
```

My guess is that the error is releated with the OCaml library Datalog (I've installed the version 0.3 from [here](https://github.com/c-cube/datalog/tree/0.3)) because the line 308 in the file is /tmp/ocamlpp466ee0 the first one in the following code

```
module Logic = Datalog.Logic.Make(struct
  type t = atom
  let equal = eq_atom
  let hash = hash_atom
  let to_string a = Utils.sprintf "%a" pp_atom a
  let of_string s = atom_of_json (Json.from_string s)
end)
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me to know what I am doing wrong.

Moreover, I would like to undestand why the file /tmp/ocamlpp466ee0 is generated each time I execute 'make'? I tried to understand by reading the Makefile but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think that something have changed in Datalog library and in some version > 0.3 functor `Datalog.Logic.Make` requires module argument with values `lock` and `unlock` declared. So, it's version problem.
2. About temporary file. As you can see, its name consists of `ocaml` literal, `pp` which means preprocessor and some number. Preprocessors in OCaml usually work this way: they read input source file and write output source files. That's why some temporary files are created.

Comment: Great! Thanks you were right I changed the version and I passed through the error but unfortunately I got the following error "Error: Unbound value Logic.db_goal"; again if anyone can help me I would appreciate. Sorry but I am very new in Ocaml.

Comment: I think that is not enough concrete question for Stack Overflow. You can try to find some inspiration in #ocaml channel on Freenode IRC.